# django передать значения из одной функции в другую

Tags: django

подскажите пожалуйста как передать значения полученные с формы, в другую функцию

> view.py

```
def index(request):
form3 = AddPostForm(request.POST)
if 'filt_tab'in request.POST:
    if form3.is_valid():
        a=form3.cleaned_data['ot']
        b=form3.cleaned_data['do']
        

return render(request, 'index.html', {
    'form3': form3
})

def movie_list(request):
news = Plan.objects.all()
return render(request, 'movie_list.html', {
    'movies': news  })



def add_movie(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = PlanForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        movie = form.save()
        return HttpResponse(
            status=204,
            headers={
                'HX-Trigger': json.dumps({
                    "movieListChanged": None,
                    "showMessage": f"{movie.title} added."
                })
            })
else:
    form = PlanForm()
return render(request, 'movie_form.html', {
    'form': form,
})
```

нужно для фильтрации по диапазону даты, чтоб в таблицу выводились нужные записи из БД.
дата "от" и дата "до" приходят в `def index(request):`
а таблица формируется в функции  `def movie_list(request):`

Answer (score 1):

```
def index(request):
    form = AddPostForm(request.POST)

    if 'filt_tab'in request.POST:

        if form.is_valid():
            a=form.cleaned_data['ot']
            b=form.cleaned_data['do']
            news = Plan.objects.filter(data__range=[ot,do])
            return render(request, 'movie_list.html', {'movies': news })

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: Добро! тока я не так выразился, movie_list.html это просто страница с таблицей в которую заносятся данные из Plan.objects, и потом на странице <tbody hx-trigger="load, movieListChanged from:body" hx-get="{% url 'movie_list' %}" hx-target="this"> подгружает эту самую заполенную таблицу, и отображает на Index.html  не соображу как мне сделать фильтрацию по диапазону дат, которые выбираю на форме